# JPA still have a reference of a deleted Entity, hence generating Exception

Tags: jpa, jakarta-ee

I delete entity `FriendWith` and create `RelationShip`. But the JPA still think `FriendWith` is there. When I deploy the EE application here is what I got in my server log.

```
[#|2010-11-05T14:31:51.190-0400|INFO|glassfish3.1|javax.enterprise.system.core.classloading.com.sun.enterprise.loader|_ThreadID=17;_ThreadName=Thread-1;|com.scholar.entity.<error> actually got transformed|#]
```

I know `com.scholar.entity.<error>` refer to `com.scholar.entity.FriendWith`

```
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
  at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
  at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:247)
  at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.security.PrivilegedAccessHelper.getClassForName(PrivilegedAccessHelper.java:88)
  at org.eclipse.persistence.descriptors.ClassDescriptor.convertClassNamesToClasses(ClassDescriptor.java:1230)
  at org.eclipse.persistence.sessions.Project.convertClassNamesToClasses(Project.java:362)
  at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerSetupImpl.deploy(EntityManagerSetupImpl.java:332)
  at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.getServerSession(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:157)
  at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.createEntityManagerImpl(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:214)
  at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.createEntityManager(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:202)
  at org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.PersistenceUnitLoader.doJava2DB(PersistenceUnitLoader.java:371)
  at org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.JPADeployer$2.visitPUD(JPADeployer.java:241)
  at org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.JPADeployer$PersistenceUnitDescriptorIterator.iteratePUDs(JPADeployer.java:279)
  at org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.JPADeployer.iterateInitializedPUsAtApplicationPrepare(JPADeployer.java:257)
  at org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.JPADeployer.event(JPADeployer.java:199)
  at org.glassfish.kernel.event.EventsImpl.send(EventsImpl.java:128)
  at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:419)
  at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:242)
  at org.glassfish.deployment.admin.DeployCommand.execute(DeployCommand.java:351)
  at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$1.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:354)
  at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:369)
  at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1077)
  at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.access$1200(CommandRunnerImpl.java:95)
  at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1226)
  at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1215)
  at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.doCommand(AdminAdapter.java:375)
  at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.service(AdminAdapter.java:209)
  at com.sun.grizzly.tcp.http11.GrizzlyAdapter.service(GrizzlyAdapter.java:168)
  at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.HK2Dispatcher.dispath(HK2Dispatcher.java:117)
  at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:234)
  at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:817)
  at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:718)
  at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:1007)
  at com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:225)
  at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:137)
  at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:104)
  at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:90)
  at com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:79)
  at com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:54)
  at com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:59)
  at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:71)
  at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:532)
  at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:513)
  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:680)

Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Uncompilable source code - class <error> is public, should be declared in a file named <error>.java
at com.scholar.entity.<error>.<clinit>(FriendWith.java:22)
... 43 more
```

if u look at the bottom of the stack trace, you can see that it said there is something wrong at `FriendWith line 22`. There is no `FriendWith.java`.  Is there a way to fix this. I clean and build the Project Folder, restart server, restart computer, but it does not fix it

Answer (score 0):

Even if you've deleted FriendWith.java, it's possible you left FriendWith.class around, and the JPA package is finding that, *somewhere*.

Search your jars, wars, ears, or whatever and your filesystem for the class file.  If you are copying your built project to a "deploy" location, make sure the .class file is not in the deploy area.